# How to use a vulkan sampler with unnormalized texture-coordinates? (without triggering VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-None-02703)

Tags: vulkan, validation-layers

So I have been using unnormalized coordinates in my texture-sampler since I find it easier to address certain parts of a texture when using it as a sprite atlas. Today I patched my workstation and recompiled everything and this error started to get reported by the validation layers:

> Validation Error: [ VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-None-02703 ] Object 0:
> handle = 0x210000000021, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET; Object
> 1: handle = 0x1c000000001c, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW; Object
> 2: handle = 0x1f000000001f, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SAMPLER; | MessageID
> = 0x30c87f64 | VkDescriptorSet 0x210000000021[] encountered the following validation error at vkCmdDrawIndexed() time: VkImageView
> 0x1c000000001c[] in Descriptor in binding #0 index 0 is used by
> VkSampler 0x1f000000001f[] that uses invalid operator. The Vulkan spec
> states: If the VkPipeline object bound to the pipeline bind point used
> by this command accesses a VkSampler object that uses unnormalized
> coordinates, that sampler must not be used with any of the SPIR-V
> OpImageSample* or OpImageSparseSample* instructions with ImplicitLod,
> Dref or Proj in their name, in any shader stage
> (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdDrawIndexed-None-02703)

I know there are various restrictions when using unnormalized texture coordinates like no mipmaps or anisotropy. Here is the (i think) relevant part from the spec:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkSamplerCreateInfo.html

> unnormalizedCoordinates controls whether to use unnormalized or
> normalized texel coordinates to address texels of the image. When set
> to VK_TRUE, the range of the image coordinates used to lookup the
> texel is in the range of zero to the image dimensions for x, y and z.
> When set to VK_FALSE the range of image coordinates is zero to one.
>
> When unnormalizedCoordinates is VK_TRUE, images the sampler is used
> with in the shader have the following requirements:
>
> ```
> The viewType must be either VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_1D or VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D.
> The image view must have a single layer and a single mip level.
> ```
>
> When unnormalizedCoordinates is VK_TRUE, image built-in functions in
> the shader that use the sampler have the following requirements:
>
> ```
> The functions must not use projection.
> The functions must not use offsets.
> ```

I meet all these requirements unless "projection" and "offsets" means "stuff that happens during rendering the texture".

**If that is the case** and unnormalized texture-coordinates cannot be used while rendering parts of the texture then:
I don't understand what this feature is for. **Where and why would one use unnormalized texture coordinates?** Furthermore many tutorials would be "missleading" like here:
https://vulkan-tutorial.com/en/Texture_mapping/Image_view_and_sampler

> The unnormalizedCoordinates field specifies which coordinate system
> you want to use to address texels in an image. If this field is
> VK_TRUE, then you can simply use coordinates within the [0, texWidth)
> and [0, texHeight) range. If it is VK_FALSE, then the texels are
> addressed using the [0, 1) range on all axes. Real-world applications
> almost always use normalized coordinates, because then it's possible
> to use textures of varying resolutions with the exact same
> coordinates.

This (just as an example) sounds like personal preference and not "method **a** works and method **b** can only be used in special circumstances and is most likely not what you want". Indeed --> when I change the sample to use unnormalized texture-coordinates the same validation-error gets reported. So can someone explain what is going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: "*This (just as an example) sounds like personal preference and not "method a works and method b can only be used in special circumstances and is most likely not what you want".*" It's still true. The vast majority of users of textures do in fact use normalized texture coordinates.

Comment: "*rendering the texture*" What does this mean? Are you rendering *to* the texture? Because you can't read from and write to the texture simultaneously; you can only do that with input attachments, which have a completely different access function.

Comment: I understand that most people use normalized texture coordinates and that is fine. I get the reasoning behind it ... in fact the tutorial even gave a good reason to do so. Still it sounds like a choice --> that I may also use unnormalized texture coordinates. But when I do, I get this error I mentioned ... so it is not really a choice of preference. I have to pick the correct method depending on what I want to do ... which leads me to my question --> What can one do with un-normalized texture coordinates when rendering the texture leads to an error?

Comment: What do I mean by "rendering the texture"? Just using the texture to color some triangles. I call vkCmdBindDescriptorSets using a set of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER and then call vkCmdDrawIndexed. In the shader the texture is accessed with texture (sampler2D, uv).

Comment: Like I mentioned ... if you look at the tutorial and just change the sampler to using un-normalized texture-coordinates you get the same error... I least I do :-)

Comment: "*Still it sounds like a choice*" It is a choice; the tutorial presents it as a choice. They're simply acknowledging the fact that most people choose to use normalized texture coordinates.

Comment: How is it a choice if I change it from normalized to un-normalized and get an validation error because of it? When I change VK_FALSE to VK_TRUE and then just need to recalculate the uv-coordinates I write to the vertex-buffer --> then it is a choice. If one possibility leads to an error it is not really a choice isn't it? Who chooses to write code that violates the spec on purpose?

Comment: The "choice" being discussed is which kind of texture coordinates to use. "How to do it correctly" is a different question, one that the tutorial does not present.

Comment: The last one is a very funny comment! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the shader the texture is accessed with texture (sampler2D, uv)

Well there's your problem. GLSL was written against OpenGL, not Vulkan. As such, it doesn't know about some of the things Vulkan allows that OpenGL normally doesn't. In OpenGL, the `texture` function always uses normalized texture coordinates. The only time it doesn't is if you're using [*rectangle* textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rectangle_Texture), which are a different texture type from 2D textures. They are an OpenGL feature that has no Vulkan analog, because in Vulkan, you can treat any texture as a "rectangle texture" (the only real feature of "rectangle textures" is that you can use non-normalized texture coordinates with them).

I don't see a mechanism in the [GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl extension](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/master/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt) that would allow the `texture` function to use non-normalized texture coordinates. So you'd have to find an alternative way to generate your SPIR-V, or you'll need to write the SPIR-V directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... that clears things up a bit. But still --> how would one use a sampler with unnormalized texture coordinates if not by calling texture(). By directly writing SPIR-V like you mentioned?

Comment: More or less, yes. That's how rarely used this feature is. Most people wanting unnormalized texture coordinates would `texelFetch`, but that requires *integer* coordinates (actual pixel locations). What you want is rectangle texture-like behavior, where you can still get linear interpolation and such.

Comment: I see ... well thank you for your time. Still I find it fascinating that using un-normalized coordinates worked flawlessly (been using that for months with texture() in the shader) and I never would have thought anything wrong if they hadn't patched the validation-layers to include a check for this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a repeat of a post on the Khrono's forums, and there is an open issue on [unnormalized texture coords here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1582).

Any call of the form:

```
 vec4 val = texture( unormSampler, pixelCoord );
```

Where unormSampler contains an unnormalized sampler results in SPIR-V opcode 87 which is the instruction OpImageSampleImplicitLod. The vulkan spec (as you noted) specifically excludes this instruction for any unnormalized texture reads.

However:

SPIR-V opcode 88 is the secret keys to the unnormalized kingdom. OpCode 88 instruction is **OpImageSampleExplicitLod**. Which is not listed (as near as I can tell) anywhere in the Vulkan spec as being an illegal operation with an unnormalized sampler.

And the secret GLSL instruction that maps to opcode 88 is **textureLod**. Here is a code sample using it.

```
// Set this up just like usual, except use a unnormalized sampler
layout(binding = 23) uniform sampler2D unormSampler;

void main()
{
    vec4 val = textureLod( unormSampler, pixelCoord, 0); // 0 is the mipmap level to sample from
}
```

I didn’t try other mipmap levels ( I vaguely remember the Vulkan Spec saying something about no mipmaps with unnormalized coordinates.).

I did try VK_FILTER_LINEAR and VK_FILTER_NEAREST for the sample and they both worked as expected. (my test has artifacts that show up when using VK_FILTER_NEAREST)

Here are a list of things that don’t work with GLSL, Vulkan, and unnormalized samplers:

1. Using sampler2Drect – Generates errors when loading the SPIR-V module

2. Using any version of texture(blablabla); – results in opcode 87 which is a no no per Vulkan spec
3. Using samplerBuffer’s – again the Spec says no with unnormalized samplers